API call in SSRS Reports using Custom Code
I have a dataset tied to SSRS Report, the dataset has SSN field encrypted and we have designed an API to decrypt that SSN.
The encryption technique used is 3DES.
The API URL is https://reporting.azurewebsites.net/api/Reporting/GetDecryptedSSN?EncryptedSSN={EncryptedSSNhere}.
The reponse body is:
{
"code": 0,
"message": "Services are up",
"data": "234-23-4234"
}
My question is:
Can I use the above API in Custom Code of SSRS and display the decrypted SSN in a column.
I tried few vb net codes from google and nothing seems working.
